# Linux Thread priority , behaviour is abnormal

Tags: linux, multithreading, thread-priority

In the below code snippet, I am creating 6 threads. Each with different priorities. The priority is mentioned in global priority array. I am doing a continuous increment of global variables inside each thread based on thread index. I was expecting the count to be higher if thread priority is higher. but my output is not adhering to priority concepts pl. refer to the output order shown below. I am trying this out on Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux kernel 4.10.

```
O/P,

Thread=0

Thread=3

Thread=2

Thread=5

Thread=1

Thread=4

pid=32155 count=4522138740

pid=32155 count=4509082289

pid=32155 count=4535088439

pid=32155 count=4517943246

pid=32155 count=4522643905

pid=32155 count=4519640181
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define FAILURE -1
#define MAX_THREADS 15
long int global_count[MAX_THREADS];
/* priority of each thread */
long int priority[]={1,20,40,60,80,99};

void clearGlobalCounts()
{
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<MAX_THREADS;i++)
                global_count[i]=0;
}

/**
     thread parameter is thread index
**/
void funcDoNothing(void *threadArgument)
{
        int count=0;
        int index = *((int *)threadArgument);
        printf("Thread=%d\n",index);
        clearGlobalCounts();
        while(1)
        {
                count++;
                if(count==100)
                {       
                        global_count[index]++;
                        count=0;
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
        int i=0;
        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(priority)/sizeof(long int);i++)
            create_thread(funcDoNothing, i,priority[i]);
        sleep(3600);
        for(i=0;i<sizeof(priority)/sizeof(long int);i++)
        {
                printf("pid=%d count=%ld\n",getpid(),
                                global_count[i]);
        }
}

create_thread(void *func,int thread_index,int priority)
{
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    struct sched_param schedParam;
    void *pParm=NULL;
    int id;
    int * index = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *index = thread_index;
    void *res;
    /* Initialize the thread attributes */
    if (pthread_attr_init(&attr))
    {
            printf("Failed to initialize thread attrs\n");
            return FAILURE;
    }

    if(pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO))
    {
            printf("Failed to pthread_attr_setschedpolicy\n");
            return FAILURE;
    }

    if (pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO))
    {
            printf("Failed to setschedpolicy\n");
            return FAILURE;
    }

    /* Set the capture thread priority */
    pthread_attr_getschedparam(&attr, &schedParam);;
    schedParam.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO) - 1; 
    schedParam.sched_priority = priority;
    if (pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedParam))
    {
            printf("Failed to setschedparam\n");
            return FAILURE;
    }    
    pthread_create(&id, &attr, (void *)func, index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [pthread_attr_setschedparam](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setinheritsched.3.html) says:

> In order for the parameter setting made by
>   pthread_attr_setschedparam() to have effect when calling
>   pthread_create(3), the caller must use pthread_attr_setinheritsched(3)
>   to  set
>          the inherit-scheduler attribute of the attributes object attr to PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED.

So you have to call `pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED)` , for example:

```
   if (pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_attr_setinheritsched");
    }
    pthread_create(&id, &attr, (void *)func, index);
```

Note: Your code produces a lot of compiler warnings, you need to fix those. You do not want to try to test code which have a lot of undefined behavior - as indicated by some of the warnings. You should probably lower the sleep(3600) to just a few seconds, since when you get your threads running under SCHED_FIFO, they will hog your CPU and the machine appears freezed while they are running.

Comment: thanks for input, behaviour seems to be much better. I corrected all warnings . 3600 was experimental just to make sure initial scheduling latency not to  impact on count. o/p now is,pid=31068 count=0
pid=31068 count=15
pid=31068 count=56961864
pid=31068 count=56964895
pid=31068 count=57002126
pid=31068 count=56688136 still highest priority task behavior is not so consistent. I tried with 30sec sleep , I will give try with higher delay. Now I have run program as root why is that limitation ?